# Remove the duplicate values from cursor in android

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I have an application where in I have to show the contact list in the device.For this I am using Simple cursor Adapter.but I am facing a problem of duplication.
The contacts having more than one numbers are displayed twice in the listview.
So is it possible to remove the Duplicate contact names from Cursor so that they are not displayed more than once in listview?

Comment: The suggestion to use a MatrixCursor in this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801533/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-distinct-contacts-in-android solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you query cursor try to set DISTINCT column, it makes sure that rows will be unique

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get you. How can I set DISTINCT column?

Comment: Maybe i didn't get the idea initially.  I think you need to use GROUP BY when query a cursor. Something like
SELECT _id, your_unique_column FROM table_name GROUP BY your_unique_column

Comment: How to use GROUP BY when querring the contact list. I mean along with contentresolver.query method....

Answer (score 0):

To remove the duplicate rows in Cursor's result set, use `GROUP BY` in the select query. For instance:

```sql
SELECT * FROM CONTACTS GROUP BY ID;
```